# Y Axis wrong index

Tags: r, graph, dataframe, lattice

Im reading a book and I found this code. Which I tried and im a little bit confused about the graph im getting.

This is Data Sample.

```
 consumption[sample(1:nrow(consumption), 5, replace=F),]
                    Food  Units Year    Amount
8  Fruits and Vegetables Pounds 1980 603.57948
31    Caloric sweeteners Pounds 1995 144.08113
16 Fruits and Vegetables Pounds 1985 630.24491
28                  Eggs Number 1995 232.28203
19    Fish and Shellfist Pounds 1990  14.94411
```

[image]

And im getting this graph. Which the Y indexes are numbers from 1 to 20, that are not the correct "Amounts".

[image]

What can I do so the Amount index in the Y axis shows correctly?

Comment: I will need my glasses :) could you reproduce the code in your post instead of using an image. You also use dput() to include your dataset in your post.

Answer (score 0):

The figure you show is just like the one in the book, [R in a Nutshell](http://web.udl.es/Biomath/Bioestadistica/R/Manuals/r_in_a_nutshell.pdf), that provided you with the code.  Actually, the book provides the code for two different versions of the same plot.  I suggest trying them both.

```
library(nutshell)
data(consumption)

library(lattice)
dotplot(Amount ~ Year | Food, consumption)
dotplot(Amount ~ Year | Food, consumption, 
  aspect="xy", scales=list(relation="sliced", cex=.4))
```

Comment: Yes, nothing. The only problem is that the Y axis is showing numbers from 1 to 49 instead of the correct Amount like 645 etc..

Comment: `dotplot` is used to display "categories".  If you want to display the values as in a scatterplot, try `xyplot` instead, e.g., `xyplot(Amount ~ Year | Food, consumption)`.